# An episode from an old horror series with human sacrifice

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, horror

I am trying to identify and purchase an episode from one of the old horror or supernatural tv series.  I don't remember if it was Twilight Zone, or The Outer Limits, or Night Gallery or Tales from the Darkside, etc.  I believe it was B&W; I don't remember the decade

As I recall it, the plot was something like:

A man visits a town and encounters a young woman who is hiding from a mob intent on killing her.  The townspeople, it turns out, periodically sacrifice one of the town's residents in an effort to appease a horrible monster.  They believe that if they fail to make the sacrifice, the monster will destroy them all.

The townspeople corner the couple and the man makes a passionate plea in the woman's defense.  He points out that:

- none of the townspeople have every seen the monster
- none of the townspeople have ever known anyone who has seen the monster
- other than legend, there is no evidence that the monster even exists
- the only danger to the community is fear and if they can overcome the fear, they will be free of the fictitious "monster" forever.

His perfect logic and moving persuasion convinces them that he is correct.  The mob agrees not to sacrifice the young woman.

Of course at this point the monster arrives and destroys them all!

Can anyone point me the series and the episode??

**EDIT:**

The episode may have been titled *"The Beast"*

Comment: Do you remember the year\decade at all (was it in color or B&W)?

Comment: @Walt  I believe it was B&W ..............I don;t remember the decade

Comment: Now that I remember, the townspeople kept referring to 'The Beast'. It was supposed to show up if anyone played music or sang.

Answer (score 4):

Night Visions (2000 TV series), episode was called [Harmony](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0660992/?ref_=ttep_ep19). It's in color and you can probably watch it on [Youtube](https://youtu.be/7AwWymP2-4w?t=1376).

> Eli's car have broke down and the nearest town is a small place called Harmony. Everyone there seem awfully nice, but for some reason no one sings, even hymns at a funeral, and no one plays music either. Eli meets a cute local woman, who find him lodging while his car is being repaired, but her young brother warns Eli that the townsfolk are a highly superstitious bunch that will even outright kill to prevent anyone from singing, playing or listening to music, because they believe in an ancient legend that playing or listening to music or even singing in the town will awaken an ancient demon they call The Beast that will go on a bloody rampage. Eli tries to dissuade the townsfolk from continuing with their ban on music, but what if the legend is real?

Comment: Thank you for assisting the community. Ideas for framing an answer should include describing your sources along with a synopsis of what they said, and/or adding links to the resources and visuals you’ve found. I hope you enjoy participating.